# Execute permissions on downloaded file

Tags: bash, shell, download, sh, chmod

I have made a script for installing a control panel.
I've uploaded the script to a server so people can wget it to their machines.
The only issue is that you have to chmod it after download. Is there a way to remove this step? How would I go about keeping 755 perms on the downloaded script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user downloads the file, the file will automatically get some default permission. In UNIX, each user will have a default set of permissions which apply to all files created by that user, unless you explicitly set it to something else.

This default is called the `umask`, after the command used to change it. It is either inherited from the login process, or set in the `.shrc` or `.login` file which configures an individual account, or it can be run manually.

Typically the default configuration is equivalent to typing 'umask 22' which produces permissions of:

```
-rw-r--r-- for regular files, or
drwxr-xr-x for directories.
```

In other words, user has full access, everyone else (group and other) has read access to files, lookup access to directories. As you see above, the **execution access is not default for files**.

Hence you need to explicitly change it.