# Calicoctl error: "bash: /usr/local/bin/calicoctl: Permission denied ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, yaml, calico

I installed Calicotl in my Ubunt trough this command:

`curl -O -L https://www.projectcalico.org/builds/calicoctl`

But, when I have to try this command in the terminal

```
calicoctl apply -f calico.yaml
```

I have this error

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/calicoctl: Permission denied
```

So, how can I fix that? Thank you very much! I try to this that with sudo but, it does not work etiher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute permissions on downloaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866553/execute-permissions-on-downloaded-file)

Comment: (Aside: That link is directly to a statically linked, compiled ELF binary. Suppose it makes me a bit old-school, but the idea of just running a binary off some random project's web site -- without even having a distro to vouch that it came from given sources, built with given steps, and was signed with a tightly-controlled release key only after passing their QA -- gives me the heebies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue (if it isn't obvious) is that the user you are running the command as does not have the permissions to execute it. As @CharlesDuffy noted in the comment's:

> If it's just direct output from `curl -o`, there won't be any `x` bits at all, so I'd expect `rw-r--r--` or `rw-rw-r--`, depending on the active umask

What do the permissions look like for the executable? You can find that by running:

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/calicoctl`

The results of the above command will output something similar to:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1680446 Jul 16 11:56 /usr/local/bin/calicoctl`

Where the `rw-r--r--` portion refers to the allowed permissions of the Owner, Group, and World/Global respectively in three letter chunks. [You can read more about how permissions work here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

I have a feeling you're results look similar to `rw-r--r--` which would mean no one has the ability to execute. It's common that all binary located in `/usr/local/bin` are owned by `root`, are in the `root` group, and have permissions set to either `rwxrwxrwx` (where everyone can Read/Write/Execute) or `rwxr-xr-x` (where the Owner can Read/Write/Execute but Group members and Global can only Read/Execute.)

To can try to adjust you're permissions to `rwxrwxr-x` with

`sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/bin/calicoctl`

and see if that works. [`chmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) is the tool used to change permissions. Again, see [this link for more info on permissions in Ubuntu/GNU+Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

For reference, here is a numeric breakdown of user permissions:

```
7 - full (rwx)
6 - read and write (rw-)
5 - read and execute (r-x)
4 - read only (r--)
3 - write and execute (-wx)
2 - write only (-w-)
1 - execute only (--x)
0 - none (---)
```

<sup>You can also probably just run your initial command with `sudo` but that's not a solution, just a workaround</sup>

Comment: If it's just direct output from `curl -o`, there won't be any `x` bits at all, so I'd expect `rw-r--r--` or `rw-rw-r--`, depending on the active umask.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point, I just assumed OP had run an installer `.sh` script but that's likely not the case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Updated the answer to quote you, thanks.